# Pluralization in mongoose/angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongoose

I have an issue with pluralization in Mongoose that Im sure is easy to fix but I cant figure it out myself.

So, I have a Model called "Eventinstance" and a controller called "eventinstances". Either mongoose or angular is doing something with the pluralization on this.

When I have link like this (via Angular in a view):

```
(<a href="" ng-click="remove(eventinstance)" >Remove</a>)
```

It does a DELETE to: http://localhost.com/eventinstances?eventinstancesId=5278fb0792b06cad0d000002   ---404 (Not Found)

When it should go to: http://localhost.com/eventinstances/5278fb0792b06cad0d000002

What do you think could be causing this?

Many thanks,

kseudo

Comment: I think the `remove()` function is causing it...

Comment: Yes you need to post your angular controllor `remove()` code. Mongoose has zero to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong declaration of your resource in Angular.

Declare it:

```
$resource('http://localhost.com/eventinstances/:id', {id: '@eventinstancesId'});
```

not as

```
$resource('http://localhost.com/eventinstances/');
```

If you omit `:id` in your declaration, `eventinstancesId` is appended as parameter after ? in your URL.

More info: [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

Comment: I dont know how you managed to figure it out from the data I gave but many thanks for helping me with this. I just could not see where the problem lay until you pointed it out